# Moto G on Lollipop is auto-locking the screen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, lock-screens, motorola-moto-g

After Lollipop update, Moto G 2nd generation phone is auto-locking even the time for autolock if undisturbed is set for 5 mins. Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings and then to security and turn off *power button instantly locks*